# Add scalar for jsonb column with Hibernate 6

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have some legacy code from an old Spring Boot application using Hibernate 5 and Spring Data JPA. There is this method that retrieves data from a PostgreSQL table which includes a `jsonb` column using a NativeQuery like so:

```kotlin
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable")
  .unwrap(NativeQuery::class.java)
  .addScalar("config", JsonBinaryType(Map::class.java))
  // I skipped other calls to addScalar
  .resultList
```

I could not find anything on how to rewrite this for Hibernate 6. The `addScalar` method no longer takes a `Type` parameter, but instead a `BasicTypeReference` or even a simple `Class`.
I've tried `addScalar("config", Map::class.java)` or `addScalar("config", JsonBinaryType::class.java)` without success. Passing nothing for the type parameter works but the value of the config column is a plain String instead of being parsed as a Map. The issue seems to be only with the jsonb column.

Thanks for any suggestion!